# the script does not work using textarea div

Tags: jquery

I use this code

```js
 var textarea = $('#mess');
var typingStatus = $('#typing_on');
var lastTypedTime = new Date(0); // it's 01/01/1970, actually some time in the past
var typingDelayMillis = 5000; // how long user can "think about his spelling" before we show "No one is typing -blank space." message
function refreshTypingStatus() {




    if (!textarea.is(':focus') || textarea.val() == '' || new Date().getTime() - lastTypedTime.getTime() > typingDelayMillis) {
        typingStatus.html('No one is typing -blank space.');
    } else {
        typingStatus.html('User is typing...');
    }
}
function updateLastTypedTime() {
    lastTypedTime = new Date();
}

setInterval(refreshTypingStatus, 100);
textarea.keypress(updateLastTypedTime);
textarea.blur(refreshTypingStatus);
```

the code shown works if I use this textarea

```js
<textarea id="mess" rows="2" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

works, but I use a div box for the textarea, this:

```html
<div class="emojionearea-editor" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Scrivi il messaggio qui, e invialo in chat..." tabindex="0" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"></div>
```

Can you help me figure out how to make it work for textarea divos? does not work if I use div

Answer (score 0):

I have a working demo on codepen.
The line that I changed is
if (!textarea.is(':focus') || textarea.val() == '' || new Date().getTime() - lastTypedTime.getTime() > typingDelayMillis)

TextArea has value but since your using a div I used text, html would probably work as well.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jgVQZW?editors=1111

```
if (!textarea.is(':focus') || textarea.text() == '' || new Date().getTime() - lastTypedTime.getTime() > typingDelayMillis)
```

Comment: Try it now, it looks like the last save I thought I did didn't work sorry.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jgVQZW?editors=1111

Comment: Glad I could help,